# does co.uk domains need a uk citizen?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, country-specific

I am a us citizen based in the us. I would like to register a co.uk domain. Do I need to be a uk citizen or have some other sort of connection to the uk to register that domain?

For instance, .ca (canada) requires this and that is why I ask.

thx

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no restrictions like that for .co.uk domains. You can go to any major registrar and register one if it's available.

If you would like more information this is the official Registry of .uk domains and their rules: http://www.nominet.org.uk/registrants/aboutdomainnames/rules/

http://www.nominet.org.uk/disputes/legalinfo/entities/

Comment: +1 - A company I work for has no physical presence or registered entity in the UK but does business there with a .co.uk domain name

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you either have to have citizenship, be a resident or have a UK registered company.

http://www.ntchosting.com/domains/co.uk.html

Comment: I think that company is not telling the truth because the official body for uk domain names says it's OK.

Comment: That information is definitely wrong. Even the video on that page contradicts that information. I certainly wouldn't use that company!